# Change colour in PhpStorm scroll error message preview

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

With the current colour scheme the text is unreadable and I would like to change it. I am not sure what they are called in color scheme settings, so I am not sure what to change.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change it. Here's the bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180736

Comment: Thanks for the information. At least I know its being looked after.